# Mark Occurrences not coming in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image]

You can see in the image, the variable `classId` is marked with some special colors, this is very helpful in the case of knowing where and all that variable is used in a particular block, same in the case of methods also. But in my `Eclipse Galileo` only for a particular `workspace` these **marks** are not appearing. The above image is taken from a different `workspace`, there it is working fine, but in that particular `workspace` it is not working that too only sometimes.

Workspace image for which this is not working

[image]

I have clicked on reference `to` which is visible in other portions of code, but not highlighted

Can anybody explain how can I bring it back in my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Can it be, that in the Workspace where it isn't working your Project is not a Java Project? Can you give a screenshot of the non working one

Comment: @Jens, I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the 'Mark Occurences' setting. This is selected by the 'Toggle Mark Occurences' button on the toolbar:

[image: Toggle Mark Occurrences Button]

You may have to customize the perspective to see this button.

There is also a keyboard shortcut - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on macOS).

For Java files there are also settings in the Preferences in 'Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences'. Some editors for other languages have similar preferences.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, that solved the issue, actually the button was not **on** in this particular workspace

Comment: Yes, you may have to customize the perspective to turn on the button.